# Why does this code fail to get the right number of days since the epoch Jan 1 1970?

Tags: java, android, calendar

I am trying to get the number of days since jan 1 1970 from  a Calendar after using  a datepicker. I want the code to work on Android ver 4.03 but the days returned by the code are the same for now and for a date in the past as shown by this log.d output :

```
MaxweightActivity: onDateSet picked 2017  month 1 day 5 days=17208 now=17208
```

what am I doing wrong?

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    long days;
    long now;
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        //todays date is 2017 feb 10
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar d = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        d.set(year, month, day);
        d.roll(Calendar.SECOND,1);

        //days = c.getTimeInMillis()/(1000*60*60*24);
        now = System.currentTimeMillis()/(1000*60*60*24);

        days = d.getTimeInMillis()/(1000*60*60*24);


        Log.d(TAG, "onDateSet picked "+year+"  month "+ month+ " day "+day+ " days="+days + " now="+now );

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user

        long dd = days;
        Log.d(TAG, "onDateSet picked "+year+"  month "+ month+ " day "+day+ " days="+days + " now="+now );
    }


}
```

Comment: In the code you have shared, `now` and `days` are set to the same date instant, except `days` will be one second later. So the output is expected, unless I'm missing something. Also, you're not sharing the code that _calls_ `onDateSet()` (maybe it's called automatically by the date picker?)

Comment: In any case, you're not adjusting the value of `days` within `onDateSet()`, which seems to be the problem.

Comment: Right Mick, in my head the values were being passed in to onDateSet direct from the call to new DatePickerDialog.  Will retest soon, thanks!